# PhoneGap - Build faild

Tags: ionic-framework, phonegap-build, phonegap

I try to build a app on **build.phonegap.com** and getting following error-

```
Error - An icon specified in your config.xml could not be found. Make sure all icons specified in your config.xml exist in your app package.
```

Seemded I have checked every resource present on resource folder.

Here is my config.xml resource -

```
<platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the Log button to open up the build log in another tab. Search for the icon error - it should tell you the exact icon that it thinks is missing. In my experience, it could be:

- The path specified in "src" is wrong. Note that it's relative to the config.xml file. [More info here](https://blog.phonegap.com/phonegap-7-0-1-now-on-build-and-it-includes-some-important-changes-89087fe465f5).
- The image is not there
- Image filename is misspelled/incorrect